# Open excel output with xlsxwriter from temporary file fail

Tags: python, excel, temporary-files, xlsxwriter

I'm creating a xlsx output with `xlsxwriter` into a temporary file using `tempfile` module, I store the path to this temporary file inside a variable that I later use in another script to open it.

The problem is that sometimes opening the file fails with the error :

```
"[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/xls5TnVsx'"
```

Sorry I don't have an exact idea about the frequency of this problem occurring but it seems like it happens from time to time, so I don't understand why...

This is how I save into a temporary file :

```
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix="xls",delete=False)
xlsfilename = f.name
```

Then to create the xlsx output :

```
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename)
ws = wb.add_worksheet(sheetName)
# Write header
....
# Write data
for row, row_data in enumerate(data, start=1):
    for column, key in enumerate(headers):
        ....
wb.close()
f.close()
```

Then in a Python CGI script I use the variable xlsxfilename which is the path to the script to open it :

```
print "Content-type: application/msexcel"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="+xlsfilename
print
try :
    print open(xlsfilename,"rb").read()
finally:
    try:
        xlsfilename.close()
    except:
        pass

os.unlink(xlsfilename)
```

What am I doing wrong here and any ideas on how to solve this by maybe using another method to storing into a temporary file?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue here is that your program is overwriting the created file with its own output, as the

```
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename)
```

statement creates a new file. The conditions under which this might be deleted will depend on when the named temporary file is deleted (technically this happens on `close()`).

You should think about using [`mkstemp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp) instead, since you already explicity delete the file you are creating. Overwriting that file, whose name is guaranteed unique and which is not deleted automatically, should be more controllable.